# What is the PostgreSQL call to remove an whole object from a JSONB array of Objects

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, jsonb, delete-record

table: TEST1
jsonB column: COLUMN1

```
[{a: 1, b: 2, c:3},
{a: 4, b: 5, c:6},
{a: 7, b: 8, c:9}]
```

I want to select on the value of a = 4 and remove the whole object it is part of for result as below
`[{a: 1, b: 2, c:3},`
`{a: 7, b: 8, c:9}]`

I can locate record with `WHERE COLUMN1->>'a' = 4`

but I have not been able to figure out or how to find this basic use case: eg delete an object from an array as part of a JSONB column

For one or many records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
CREATE TABLE tab( ID INT, jsdata jsonb )

INSERT INTO tab VALUES
(1,'[{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c":3},{"a": 4, "b": 5, "c":6},{"a": 7, "b": 8, "c":9}]'::jsonb),
(2,'[{"a": 4, "b": 2, "c":3},{"a": 9, "b": 5, "c":6},{"a": 7, "b": 8, "c":9}]'::jsonb)


UPDATE tab t1
SET jsdata = ( SELECT jsonb_agg(elm)
FROM tab t2
CROSS JOIN jsonb_array_elements(jsdata) AS elm
WHERE (elm->>'a')::int != 4
AND t2.ID = 2
GROUP BY t2.ID )
WHERE t1.ID = 2
```

```
RESULT:
  1,'[{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c":3},{"a": 4, "b": 5, "c":6},{"a": 7, "b": 8, "c":9}]', 
  2,'[{"a": 9, "b": 5, "c":6},{"a": 7, "b": 8, "c":9}]'
```

Comment: Barbaros: Is there a better way to do the update (eg remove object in array) of a specific ID. This works but suspect it is not the most efficient way to accomplish..

Comment: can I remove an object from the array as shown above and replace it with a new object with the same a value eg 4 but different b and c. I need to update multiple values in an object inside a json b array. Looking for the best way to do that

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use your filtering logic reversely as `WHERE COLUMN1->>'a' != 4` by replacing equality with inequality by contribution of `jsonb_array_elements()` function, and then apply `jsonb_agg()` function as below :

```
SELECT ID, jsonb_agg(elm) AS "Result"
  FROM tab t
 CROSS JOIN jsonb_array_elements(jsdata) AS elm
 WHERE (elm ->> 'a')::int != 4
 GROUP BY ID
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=a9cc200715591fec648c37ac9eeb3511)</kbd>

Comment: I think this is missing a `GROUP BY`, or should use a subquery like in `SELECT (SELECT jsonb_agg(elm) FROM jsonb_array_elements(…) WHERE …) AS result FROM tab`

Comment: Hi @Bergi , seems like redunant to use a `GROUP BY`. Have you checked out the demo ?

Comment: Yes, you can see it in your demo as well - it stops working when there are multiple rows in `tab`. OP wrote "*For one or many records*".

Comment: well, you're right from that poin of view, thanks @Bergi . I've edited.